# GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH returns 1

Tags: opengl, glsl, glew

EDIT: clarification. I'm not checking if the compile failed, I'm just looking for ***logs***. I'm checking COMPILE_STATUS later in the code. (See the `GLint isCompiled` that is not used in this piece.)

Why does this return 1, it's supposed to be **0**?

`glGetShaderiv(compiled, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);`

```cpp
    GLuint compiled = glCreateShader(shader->Type);
    GLchar const *shader_source = code.c_str();
    GLint const shader_length = code.size();

    glCheck(glShaderSource(compiled, 1, &shader_source, &shader_length));
    glCheck(glCompileShader(compiled));

    GLint isCompiled = 0;
    char msg[512];

    // Check if everything went ok
    glGetShaderiv(compiled, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);

    // Getting information about the compile
    GLsizei infoLogLength = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(compiled, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    if (infoLogLength > 0)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(compiled, 512, &infoLogLength, msg);
        printf("Shader [%s:%s] error when compiling[%d]: \n%s", shader->Name.c_str(), GetShaderTypeAsString(shader->Type).c_str(), infoLogLength, msg);
    }
```

Output:

```
Shader [dust_particle_VS.glsl:Vertex Sader] error when compiling[1]:
```

The shader seems to be working fine and the game plays without problems.
I'm just thinking that it might be some warning that might benefit me to know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OpenGLs 4.6 specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) at 7.13 says:

> void GetShaderiv( uint shader, enum pname, int *params );
>
> ...
>
> If pname
>   is INFO_LOG_LENGTH, the length of the info log, including a null
>   terminator, is returned. If there is an empty info log, zero is
>   returned.

And later:

> void GetShaderInfoLog( uint shader, sizei bufSize, sizei *length, char
>   *infoLog );
>
> ...
>
> These commands return an info log string for the corresponding type of
>   object in infoLog. This string will be null-terminated even if the
>   INFO_LOG_LENGTH query returns zero.

As I undestand these sentences is that the query `INFO_LOG_LENGTH` must return *zero* for an empty info log string. And if you retrieve this string it will contain at least a null character.

My guess is that the driver you use counts (for some cases) that null-terminated char even for an empty log.

In other words, seems a driver bug.

Not a big one, because, as @NicoBolas told, you will not use the info-log as a fail-check, but for info in case of fail; and likely in this case the driver will set a string longer than 1.

Answer (score 4):

Implementations are allowed to give you an info log *even if* the shader successfully compiled. Or more to the point, the info log is not required to be empty upon a successful shader compilation. From the specification:

> A string that contains information about the last compilation attempt on a shader object, last link or validation attempt on a program object, or last validation attempt on a program pipeline object, called the info log, can be obtained...

Note that it does not say "last **failed** compilation attempt" or anything of that nature. So it doesn't matter if the info log length is 0, 1, or anything else; the info log's length cannot tell you if compilation succeeded or failed. Indeed, some implementations have been known to give you warnings in an info log even on successful compilations.

Checking the compile status is how you determine if compilation succeeded or not, not the info log.

Comment: "Checking the compile status is how you determine if compilation succeeded or not, not the info log", I don't care about this.

I'm wondering why it's 1 and not 0.

Comment: I see both 0's and 1's CONSISTENTLY on the specific shader I'm compiling.

Comment: Shader_1: Always length 0, shader_2: Always length 1.

Comment: @KimS.: Then you're asking why an implementation-dependent thing happens to have the value it does. Well, that's just how it happens to be. I mean, there could be an answer somewhere in the depths of the implementation you're using. But that answer will in no way be useful or meaningful. Nor will it be necessarily consistent with the *next* driver version, which may change the result.

Comment: @KimS I'm sorry to say, but if you are checking the shader log length as a way to determine the compile status, you are NOT following the spec. The spec allow driver implementors to return warnings via the info log, which have nothing to do with the validity of the shader code itself. To find out if the compile failed, you need to check GL_COMPILE_STATUS, end of story.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Yeah, I'm just checking if anyone has noticed the same behavior when something was wrong. Don't worry, I'm checking all the stuff later in the code, COMPILE, LINK, VALIDATION, etc.

Comment: @robthebloke, As I've mentioned several times here, I'm not checking the log size to see if the compile failed, I'm simply checking to see if there is a log AT ALL. Jesus Christ.

Comment: @KimS.: Then why does your code print "error when compiling" if a non-zero log length is produced? Why does your code query the compile status but never do anything with it? All of these things are indicative of misusing the info log as an error check, or just a missed `if(isCompiled)` statement.

Comment: @NicolBolas, You want the log to say "LOG when compiling" or what, fair enough. The compile status is not even handled in any of this code. You're focusing on the wrong thing. Look at the title.

Comment: @NicolBolas This code is right below the snippet I posted;     

```
if (isCompiled == GL_FALSE)
    {
        g_ErrorReport("Shader [%s:%s] will not be used due to an error.", shader->Name.c_str(), GetShaderTypeAsString(shader->Type).c_str());
        return -1;
    }

    return compiled;
```

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't add it in the question because it's not relevant at all to my question.

Comment: I@KimS It should be zero, but it isn't. That would be a driver bu (or an optimisation, depending on how you look at it)g. t still doesn't fix the problem that you're using the log length to determine whether an error has occurred:  "Shader [%s:%s] error when compiling[%d]: \n%s"